# How to create a trigger in SQL?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have 2 table, `booking` and `guest`:

```
booking: hotel_no(PK),guest_no(PK),date_from(PK),date_to,room_no  
guest: guest_no(PK),g_name,g_address
```

I want to create a trigger that enforce referential integrity with `Guest` table when inserting records into `Booking` table.

How can I create that trigger?

Comment: What database you use? Oracle, MySql, sqlite? what?

Comment: Im using mysql.Sorry about forgetting information

Comment: Mind writing your create tables scheme on your question? With two relared tables will do.

Comment: I cant do it now because i am using my phone and i left my stuff in my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a trigger which is quite specific to the DB you are using, I would create a [foreign key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) which is designed for that.

```
ALTER TABLE booking
ADDCONSTRAINT fk_guest
FOREIGN KEY (guest_no)
REFERENCES guest(guest_no)
```

**EDIT**

Since you need to use triggers only and there are so many examples and tutorials you can easily find on the net, I will just suggest you http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/08/mysql-check-constraint/ in addition to the [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx) mhyst provided in his comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help but my teacher asks me to create a trigger in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `booking_trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `booking` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    // Your query
     insert into Guest(..........)
END
```